# Gradient rounded borders and display:block

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients, display

**EDIT:** It seems the snippet works fine if I remove z-index from the parent, but it's most certainly not doing that on my forum. Take a look: http://pjonline.tk/index.php?act=idx

So, I have something a little complicated set up. Basically, I'm making a forum, right? And each forum has a description. Since some go on to multiple lines, I have it set as display:block so there's no trouble with wrapping.

Now, I want a kind of fancy look for these. Specifically, this:
    [image]

Except, uh, y'know. Properly made. My first attempt was with percentage border-radius, but it was [squished in too much](http://prntscr.com/d2yvvr). So I decided to create a div around it that'd have normal borders, and with both borders having a transparency fade so it'd look seamlessly like the display above.

I wandered around Google for a while and eventually found the idea to use ::after to get a gradient rounded border. Unfortunately, due to the display:block, the ::after's background is appearing on top of the actual background. ::before didn't help either.

So um, lil bit stuck on what to do ^^; I'd really like a border to what I've set, but nothing's working out and you *of course* just can't set the colour of top-left/bottom-right >>

Is there a way I could do this?

Current codes:

```css
body { /* only here to set font size/family */
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: arial;
}

#wrapper { /* a container these are held in with a specific z-index */
  position:relative;
  z-index:7;
}

.forum-desc {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 387px 115px 387px 115px / 36px 22px 36px 22px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 335px;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: enter;
  text-align-last: center;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.forum-desc::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  content: '';
  border-radius: 387px 115px 387px 115px / 36px 22px 36px 22px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <span class="forum-desc">Various information pertaining to rules and the proper way to act on the forum and game.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't removing `z-index: 2` from the parent achieve what you want?

Comment: @Harry No, because then the ::after background vanishes entirely. One of the containers its in has a z-index of 7, due to some other elements on the forum.

Comment: Is it? I tried in Chrome (albeit, an older version) and it does show the pseudo-element's background as a border-like thing. (*Edit:* In that case, please create a complete example. If you leave it as-is, you'd probably get another answer like what I just gave.)

Comment: @Harry http://prntscr.com/d2z7i1 Most definitely doesn't.

Comment: Your question doesn't have the point you mention in comments about the `z-index` on the container. Did you try removing the `z-index: 2` in the snippet in question?

Comment: @Harry Yes, but again... It isn't doing anything, even if I removed z-index on the container. And oh shoot, missed that edit. Will update my post now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... Apparently it was my `.row4`'s `background-color` that was blocking it all from layering properly... Bizarre, but an issue resolved by assigning `.row4` a `z-index`, I guess. I did everything right, just had conflicting code x:

Answer (score 1):

Here u go my frnd...

css:-

```
body { /*only here to set font size/family */
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.forum-desc {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 387px 0px 387px 0px / 36px 22px 36px 22px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 335px;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: enter;
  text-align-last: center;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  position: relative;
}

.forum-desc::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  content: '';
  border-radius: 387px 0px 387px 0px / 36px 22px 36px 22px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: Right, so, tell me how this is supposed to work on my forum? Because the background layering still isn't working on it.

Comment: have u added my given css? @Foxwells paste the css code at the end of ur css file and run it.

Comment: No. It wasn't correct. All I had to do was mess around with my z-index layering to solve my issue. I didn't need help designing. I needed help //getting them to appear//, which your answer didn't do.